# What is the proper way to use moment.js to process php dates in a view?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, momentjs

I want to display a time-ago date in text, and I like the moment.js formatter.  I am using php to echo the current date, but haven't found a good time-ago formatter, hence why I want to use moment.js.

I was thinking of echoeing `{12345678}` as a unix timestamp in my html page and then using jquery to replace each token after formatting using the moment.js `fromNow()` function on document.ready.

Is this a good solution?  If so, how can I iterate through all the tokens, process the dates, and then replace the content?

I have read on how to use the `replaceWith()` and `replace`, but they don't allow me to process the token.

This may be a far-off approach as there might just be a simple php time-ago formatter helper...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

So....

Here is my solution.

JS:

```
// time formatter
$( "[data-time-format]" ).each(function() {
    var el = $( this );
    switch(el.attr("data-time-format")) {
        case "time-ago":
        var timeValue = el.attr("data-time-value")
        var strTimeAgo = moment.unix(timeValue).fromNow();
        el.text(strTimeAgo);
        break;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<span data-time-format="time-ago" data-time-value="{UNIX TIMESTAMP}"></span>
```

This Js snippet iterates through all elements with an attribute "data-time-format" and then uses a switch statement for processing.  I am using a switch as i will use this data attribute for other timestamp processing, so I wanted flexibility.

The Js should be placed in document.ready.